# YQ - replace values of subfields of list based on list of values

Tags: bash, list, yaml, yq

Given a list in YAML, I want to dynamically replace all values of source.targetRevison's based on a input list to an input variable:

replace_list=[argocd,argocd-projects] 
replace_to_value=v1.0.0

yq version 4.2.x+

Input YAML:

```
server:
  additionalApplications:
    - name: argocd
      path: argocd/argocd-install
      source:
        targetRevision: feature/3-dns
    - name: argocd-projects
      source:
        path: argocd/argocd-projects
        targetRevision: feature/3-dns
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          selfHeal: true
          prune: true
    - name: argocd-tools-aks-apps
      namespace: argocd
      destination:
        namespace: argocd
        server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
      project: argocd
      source:
        targetRevision: HEAD
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          selfHeal: true
          prune: true
```

Expected output:

```
server:
 additionalApplications:
  - name: argocd
    path: argocd/argocd-install
    source:
      targetRevision: v1.0.0
  - name: argocd-projects
    source:
      path: argocd/argocd-projects
      targetRevision: v1.0.0
    syncPolicy:
      automated:
        selfHeal: true
        prune: true
  - name: argocd-tools-aks-apps
    namespace: argocd
    destination:
      namespace: argocd
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    project: argocd
    source:
      targetRevision: HEAD
    syncPolicy:
      automated:
        selfHeal: true
        prune: true
```

Current progress:

yq '.server.additionalApplications.[] | (.source.targetRevision)' argocd/argocd-install/values-override.yaml

gives me:

- feature/3-dns
- feature/3-dns
- HEAD

Comment: Also yq '.server.additionalApplications.[] | select(.name == "argocd") | (.source.targetRevision) |="v1.0.0"' -i argocd/argocd-install/values-override.yaml reduces my file to the one list entry of the solution and discards the rest, i want to keep all unmodified fields

Comment: The provided YAML is not valid. Provide a syntactically valid one

Comment: +updated: fixed yaml in the example and result to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
yq '(  .server.additionalApplications[] | 
       select(.name == ("argocd", "argocd-projects")) | 
       .source.targetRevision ) 
   |= "v1.0.0"' examples/data1.yaml
```

Explanation:
You want to update a selection of the additionalApplication entries.

- First you navigate to those entries and expand them `.server.additionalApplications[]`
- Next, we filter them by the name: `select(.name == ("argocd", "argocd-projects")`
- Now we can update their `.source.targetRevision` property.
  Importantly, note that the whole LHS expression is in brackets, as that's what we want to pass to the 'update' (|=) operator. If you don't put it in brackets, then you will see that it seems to discard everything else (because it filters first, then updates separately).

Hope that makes sense!

Disclaimer: I wrote yq.

Comment: Superb, works like a charm. I added the -i option to edit inplace and changed to input to be dynamic as well via passing an env to yq:           ( target_REVISION=v1.0.1;)                  
                                                                                                      
 REVISION=$target_REVISION yq e '(  .server.additionalApplications[] |
       select(.name == ("argocd", "argocd-projects")) |
       .source.targetRevision )
   |= env(REVISION)' -i argocd/argocd-install/values-override.yaml

Comment: would love to give a +1 but i am still under 15 ratings... soon!